# Checking if model is null fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
    @model Seriebeheer.Domain.Serie

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Verijwder serie";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    }

    @if (Model != null) 
    {
    <h1>Verwijder @Model.Name</h1>

    Weet u zeker dat u deze serie wilt verwijderen? Dit zal ook alle afleveringen van deze serie verwijderen!<br />

    using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "SerieAdmin", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Hidden("id", @Model.ID)
        <input type="submit" value="Verwijder" />
    }

        <br />
} else 
{ <b>Deze serie bestaat niet</b> }
```

The above code fails on the "weet u zeker..." line (expected ;). What's wrong with this null check?

Thanks

EDIT:
The exact error message:
 Foutbericht van compiler: CS1002: ; wordt verwacht

Translateed: error message from compiler: CS1002: expected ;

Comment: what's the exact error?

Comment: **Please translate the error into English**  Please provide the code where you define and declare `Model`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor engine treats everything in curly brackets `{ }` as code if it is not between html tags. For this one to work you have to add `<span>` before Weet and `</span>` after verwijderen!
 to this to work. (OF course you can use any html tag you like/want :)

Answer (score 0):

Better change this

```
  Weet u zeker dat u deze serie wilt verwijderen? Dit zal ook 
   alle afleveringen van deze serie verwijderen!
```

to

```
<text>  Weet u zeker dat u deze serie wilt verwijderen? Dit zal ook
       alle afleveringen van deze serie verwijderen!
</text>
```

wrapping with text  node would be a better choice, which will not hurt your CSS or html 
Also the Razor view engine will not assume that its a server side code as it start with HTML tag. In your case you are writing
Html inside razor with out @{}